# Type ' ' is not assignable to type 'never' in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, typescript-eslint

I've been trying to run build in next.js but I am encountering an error again and again while linting and checking validity of types.

```
.next/types/app/page.ts:8:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof import("E:/Programming/NextJS/dashboard/src/app/page"), "metadata" | "default" | "config" | "generateStaticParams" | "revalidate" | "dynamic" | "dynamicParams" | "fetchCache" | "preferredRegion" | "runtime" | "maxDuration" | "generateMetadata", "">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'PopupContext' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'Context<iPopupContext>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

   6 |
   7 | // Check that the entry is a valid entry
>  8 | checkFields<Diff<{
     |             ^
   9 |   default: Function
  10 |   config?: {}
  11 |   generateStaticParams?: Function
```

My code is as follows:

```
type iPopupContext = {popup: boolean; setPopup: (popup: boolean) => any}
const defaultState = {popup: false, setPopup: (popup: boolean) => {}}
export const PopupContext = createContext<iPopupContext>(defaultState)
```

```
export default function Home() {
  const [popup, setPopup] = React.useState<any>(false)
  return (
    <PopupContext.Provider value={{popup, setPopup}}>

    <PopupContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Ps. code was too lengthy so I cut short with all instances of popup which could've raised error

I am pretty new with typescript so Please help me solve this issue.

I expected it to run without any type errors as npm run dev was working smooth.